# Получить url javafx

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, javafx

Ребят, всем привет, возник вопрос: как в javafx получить url страницы? Работаю с vkapi.

Делаю обычный запрос

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=x&scope=friends,notify,photos,photos,audio,video,docs,notes,pages,groups,offline&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=mobile&v=5.5&response_type=token&revoke=1
```

После авторизации и выдачи прав доступа идет редирект на url такого вида:

```
http://REDIRECT_URI#access_token= 533bacf01e11f55b536a565b57531ad114461ae8736d6506a3&expires_in=86400&user_id=8492
```

Как получить url именно этой страницы? (хочу вытащить acess_token)
Знаю, что можно воспользоваться .getLocation(), но как обратиться к форме браузера только после редиректа? Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

```
 WebEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observable, Worker.State oldValue, Worker.State newValue) {
            if (newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
               if (WebEngine.getLocation.contains("access_token")){
                  //code here
            }}}}
```